# Program (inkscape) is linked with libpng16 but loads libpng15 at runtime - Why?

Tags: gcc, linker

I compiled `inkscape` with `libpng16`. Still, `ldd` shows it requires `libpng15`. So I suspected that one of the libs linked would be the culprit. I wrote a program which recursively `ldd`'s all libraries, and none of the seems to need `libpng15`.

- Why would `inkscape` require `libpng15` *and* `libpng16` on its own?
- `Inkscape` runs fine, till I try to export a PNG image, then the message is:

  libpng warning: Application built with libpng-1.6.16 but running with 1.5.13

Note: I detected [lddtree.sh](https://github.com/slashbeast/pax-utils/blob/master/lddtree.sh), which seems to do the same, and yes, the result is the same as the script I wrote!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this one took quite a while to solve. I'm certainly not an expert in the intricacies of `gcc`, `g++`, static and dynamic linking etc., which probably accounts for part of the confusion.

What happened here? It seems that Inkscape uses two types of libraries. The normal external libraries (which can be controlled by `--enable-static` and `-shared`, but also a dozen or so internal libraries (some of which are private copies of external libraries, such as `libcroco`) which are not controlled by `--enable-static` and friends, but do request libraries on their own:

```
libcroco/libcroco.a
libavoid/libavoid.a
libgdl/libgdl.a 
libuemf/libuemf.a
libcola/libcola.a
inkgc/libinkgc.a
libvpsc/libvpsc.a
livarot/libvarot.a
2geom/lib2geom.a
libdepixelize/libdepixelize.a
util/libutil.a 
libinkversion.a
```

These 'internal' libraries seem to be always statically linked. They magically appear on the final link line. There seems to be no control over their compatibility with the shared libraries pulled in by `automake` system.

In my case, `libpng15.so` was pulled in (probably by `libcroco`, which pulled in `libgtkmm`/`libcairomm`) by the internal libraries, while `libpng16.so` was requested by the external libraries, which I carefully maintain with `libpng16`.

Slackware is a `Qt`-centric distribution, which only maintains a bare minimum of the `GTK` world. So I regularly try to update that part separately. On a moving target like `Slackware-current`, this in not always easy. On the other hand, all the searches I did to solve this problem show a reasonably large population with the same issue, most of which does not use `-current`, or even `Slackware` at all.

The solution was, of course, recompiling `libcairomm`, `libgtkmm`, and a couple of other static libs, then recompile `Inkscape`.

In hindsight, a simple check of the list of libraries in the final link command would have alerted of the problem, showing two different versions of `libpng` being included. On the other hand, this is a rather special case, as the versions have different names but have the same function, which is rather unique. Sorry about the long post - I hope this helps others with similar issues.